# Getting Masechtos for Daf Yomi

Tags: talmud-gemara, jewish-books, daf-yomi

Is there a subscription service (ala [Chayenu](https://chayenu.org/)) for Daf yomi where I can receive an easily transportable Gemara for the upcoming week(s)

Comment: I think Oz-Vehadar offers this for their paperback mesivta volumes

Comment: In addition to the answer below, artscroll has an iPad version which is perfect for learning on the go, and Koren's PDFs can serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options that I can think of:

1. **Koren Publishers** write [here](https://korenpub.com/collections/talmud-subscriptions-1):

> Subscribers to the hardcover edition will receive each volume in advance of the Daf and an email containing a link to download the PDF.  Each PDF contains the side-by-side English-Aramaic translation and commentary by Rabbi Adin Steinsaltz and  color images. Vilna page not included.

Although if you're looking for a more transportable option as far as a hard Gemara this might not be so ideal.

2. **Artscroll** run a similar offer [here](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/ctapp.html) where you can setup a standing order and receive every volume as you go through Shas. It writes as follows there:

> Receive every volume of the Digtal Schottenstein Edition of the Talmud just in time for the Daf Yomi Cycle! Sign up now and never miss having your volume in time again. There is no charge for this convenient service, and you can cancel at any time.
>
> You will automatically receive:
>
> A 20% discount off the prevailing list price (currently $9.99)
>
> Each volume will be added to your digital volumes 2 weeks before the start of that volume in the Daf Yomi Cycle - and for added convenience, automatically billed to your credit card.
>
> We will only add those volumes that you have not already purchased through ArtScroll.com - Once you click on the "Place in Cart" button, you will be given the option to exclude any volumes you already own.
>
> Why sign up for the ArtScroll Standing order rather then the Apple and Google play Monthly Subscription:
>
> The price when purchased per volume is cheaper than the the monthly subscription. Save up $100 over the course of the subscription
>
> YOU have more control of which volumes you will receive. You can indicate which volume you already have that you want to skip receiving
>
> If you want to get ahead of the daf or you want your volume early - you can purchase it whenever you want and exclude getting it later.

3. Alternatively, if taking a gemara around with you is your main priority the daf is accessible in many places online which you can print in advance, without actually purchasing a gemara. For example [Hebrewbooks](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas) and [all-daf](https://alldaf.org/p/74775) to name a couple.